# How do you use wildcards or any other special character in quotes, single quotes or backtick?

Tags: linux, special-characters, wildcard, backticks

How do you use wildcards or any other special character in quotes, single quotes or backtick?

and

How do you make it so Linux doesn't take it literally?
For example

```
echo "This is my list of file ls -l"
```

I know their is another way of doing it for example

```
echo "This is my list of file" ; ls -l
```

But I'm trying to keep the **ls -l** inside the echo.

Comment: When I type in **echo "This is my life of file ls -l"**

. . .I'm expecting to see

**echo "This is my list of file" ; ls -l**

I'm not expecting it to print out **This is my list of file ls -l**

so, I'm basically trying to figure out what special characters can I use within the **" "** or **' '** or **` `** so I can perform **ls -l** while in quotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
echo "This is my list of file $(ls -l)"
```

This will print the output of ls -l inside the echo statement.